# Altering a linked entity but then not persisting it on flush()

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am reading in a number of database rows into an array/collection, and changing some of the data within them (reducing a price) to use that altered value later in my program.

But, when I later create a new entity, which is linked through some common data (via a OneToMany relationship), the price rows are also being changed in the database.

How can I alter the contents of an entity, but then **not** have the altered entity written back to the database?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

Comment: Since the top-level entity has a field that points (indirectly) to the prices, I also had to put a `$this->doctrine->getReference('AppBundle:EntityName', $id);` into the top-level entity to avoid an issue.